# Can yaml-cpp used as header only library?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am trying to incorporate yaml-cpp in a huge project and don't want to have it as an external dependency(the project only has our internal libraries as dependencies). Is it possible to have just the headers included instead of compiling the whole project for the .lib file?

Comment: Looks like the answer is YES, thanks to the MIT license you should be able to freely do it, but the code is rather large - you'll spend a lot of time compiling it.

Comment: If you include just the headers, you're missing the implementation. You will need to include the implementation located in the non-header source files one way or the other. Whether you compile them separately and link against the generated `lib` or include them in your project and compile them along with your own source files makes little difference. *header only* just means that the whole implementation is in the header, which is evidently not the case with yaml-cpp (and is probably not trivial to do).

Comment: IMO the answer is a definite No and it's a bad practice of software development. Yamp-cpp supports cmake and it is in fact really easy to build a library out of it, specially with the new version that they are not dependent on Boost anymore.